# Why does variable expansion without $ work in expressions?

Tags: bash, variable-substitution

```
#!/bin/bash

VALUE=10

if [[ VALUE -eq 10 ]]
then
    echo "Yes"
fi
```

To my surprise, this outputs "Yes". I would have expected it to require `[[ $VALUE -eq 10 ]]`. I've scanned the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section of `man bash`, but I did not find anything to explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`[[` is bash reserved word, therefore special expansion rules such as arithmetic expansion are applied, not like in case with `[`. Also arithmetic binary operator `-eq` is used. Therefore shell looks for integer expression and if text is found at the first item it tries to expand it as parameter. It is called arithmetic expansion and is present in `man bash`.

```
RESERVED WORDS
       Reserved words are words that have a special meaning to the shell.  
       The following words are recognized as reserved 
       …
       [[ ]]

[[ expression ]]
       Return  a  status  of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of 
       the conditional expression expression.  Expressions are 
       composed of the primaries described below under CONDITIONAL 
       EXPRESSIONS.  Word splitting and pathname expansion are not 
       performed on the words between the  [[  and  ]];  tilde 
       expansion, parameter and variable expansion, >>>_arithmetic 
       expansion_<<<, command substitution, process substitution, and 
       quote removal are performed.  

Arithmetic Expansion
       …
       The evaluation is performed according to the rules listed below 
       under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.

ARITHMETIC EVALUATION
       …
       Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced 
       by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.
```

So for example:

```
[[ hdjakshdka -eq fkshdfwuefy ]]
```

will return always true

But this one will return error

```
$ [[ 1235hsdkjfh -eq 81749hfjsdkhf ]]
-bash: [[: 1235hsdkjfh: value too great for base (error token is "1235hsdkjfh")
```

Also recursion is available:

```
$ VALUE=VALUE ; [[ VALUE -eq 12 ]]
-bash: [[: VALUE: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "VALUE")
```

Comment: Why does being a reserved word mean it does arithmetic evaluation?  I can't find that documented anywhere

Comment: Ah, here it is. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57

Comment: I've included citation from `man bash` to my answer to make it clear.

Comment: @Mikel It's not directly the fact that `[[` is a reserved word, but because what's within `[[ … ]]` is not ordinary command syntax, but a conditional expression. In a conditional expression, the arguments to arithmetic operators such as `-eq` are subject to arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: Yes.  I was saying the first sentence gives that idea, which is misleading

Comment: Also from `man bash`: **word**: a sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell, also known as a token;
**name**: a word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore;
**parameter**: an entity that stores values, it can be a name, a number, or one of the special characters;
**variable**: a parameter denoted by a name, a variable has a value and zero or more attributes. Thus `1235hsdkjfh` and `81749hfjsdkhf` cannot be variables but only parameters, and thus cannot be expanded without the `$` syntax.